# integrating existing SPA app with meteor.js as backend

Tags: meteor

I have an existing SPA app . This SPA was developed with Aurelia . The app is loaded from index.html file. 
I need to host the app into meteor saving these options :
1. Meteor shouldn't build the SPA app (ignore building it each time it changed).
2. How I can request the index.html file from meteor in order to load the app .

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

As for preventing Meteor from touching your `index.html` file, you could simply place it in the `public` [special folder](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).

To serve this file, you could for example have an `iframe` which points to your file (do not include `public/` in your path, e.g. if your file is in `public/spa/index.html`, use `src="spa/index.html"`)